# One acceptor and several dynamic initiators

Tags: quickfixn

I just started my acquaintance with the FIX protocol. For this I use the QuickFIX/n library version 1.11.0. Also QuickFIXn.FIX5.0SP2 and QuickFIXn.FIXT1.1 (all versions 1.11.0)
There is an acceptor configuration.

```
[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
HeartBtInt=20
AppDataDictionary=../../../ApplicationData/FIXRTv1.xml
TransportDataDictionary=../../../ApplicationData/FIXT11.xml

FileLogPath=log
SocketAcceptPort=9823 
SocketAcceptHost = 127.0.0.1
ConnectionType=acceptor
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y

SenderCompID=TEST
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
FileStorePath=store
```

There is an initiator configuration.

```
[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=20
AppDataDictionary=../../spec/fix/FIXRTv1.xml
TransportDataDictionary=../../spec/fix/FIXT11.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y

ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=USER
TargetCompID=TEST
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1 
SocketConnectPort=9823 

StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
```

As you can see in the acceptor configuration, only DEFAULT is defined. If you add it SESSION indicating for the initiator, then everything works. Otherwise, the initiator issues an error
Connection failed: The connection was not established because The destination computer rejected the connection request. 127.0.0.1:9823

Is it possible to connect initiators unknown to it in advance to the acceptor and dynamically create sessions for them?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to be able to create acceptor sessions dynamically? If yes, that does not seem to be possible in quickfixn, see following PRs: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/pull/607 and https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/pull/650 Edit: but what do you want to do really? Just connect mutiple initiators to the same acceptor? That should be possible with multiple SESSION sections in your config file.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering if it's possible to implement the following scenario. There is a service that has access to a database with logins and passwords of initiators. The acceptor does not know in advance what sessions will be created. A request to connect to the acceptor comes from the initiator. The service acceptor checks his login and password and if the data is correct, then creates a session for the initiator and Logon him in. Thus, the initiator gets the opportunity to perform actions using the FIX protocol.

Comment: I've taken another look, this suggests you could add dynamic sessions to an acceptor, but am no expert on quickfixn: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/d40b123c26df57e7d76663a27de77a04be730a95/QuickFIXn/ThreadedSocketAcceptor.cs#L331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Christoph John .Link to comment: [One acceptor and several dynamic initiators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355317/one-acceptor-and-several-initiators#comment136398310_77355317)

Simple code that can add dynamic sessions when the acceptor is running:

```cs
var HttpServerPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5080/";
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(pathToConfig);
IApplication executorApp = new MyAcceptor();
IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
ILogFactory logFactory = new FileLogFactory(settings);
ThreadedSocketAcceptor acceptor = new ThreadedSocketAcceptor(executorApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);
HttpServer srv = new HttpServer(HttpServerPrefix, settings);

acceptor.Start();
srv.Start();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add session?");
    var answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if(answer == "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input comp:");
        var comp = Console.ReadLine();
        var dictSettings = new Dictionary();
        var sessionId = new SessionID("FIXT.1.1", "MyAcceptor", comp);
        acceptor.AddSession(sessionId, dictSettings);
    }
}

srv.Stop();
acceptor.Stop();
```

You can view the sessions created by the `HttpServerPrefix` link.